# Canvas static height Chartjs

Tags: html5-canvas, chart.js

I am using chart.js **2.3.0** to draw graph. I want to make the **height of the graph static(fixed e.g. 200px)** but also want to set the **width** to **100%**. One solution I have seen is to do:

`responsive: false`

in the graph options.
But after doing this, **width also reduces**.
Is there any best way to do it?

> static height and 100% width.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
options: {
  responsive: true, 
  maintainAspectRatio: false
}
```

It works perfectly with these options.

Comment: The key to this for me was setting a height on the direct parent of the canvas tag.  I'm using bootstrap 4 cards, and an empty card apparently has a height of 0.

Answer (score 13):

To make it work, you also need to wrap your chart in a dedicated  element in addition of using these options:

```
options: {
    responsive: true, 
    maintainAspectRatio: false
}
```

Example:

```
<div>
    <canvas id="xxx"></canvas>
</div>
```

---

See official documentation:

> Detecting when the canvas size changes can not be done directly from the CANVAS element. Chart.js uses its parent container to update the canvas render and display sizes. However, this method requires the container to be relatively positioned and dedicated to the chart canvas only.

Comment: you saved my day bro ;) , it's necessary to wrap the canvas in a div

Comment: Great, you are a great guy.

Answer (score 6):

This question has an accepted answer, but it was only part of the answer for me.  What isn't clear from the documentation, at least to me, is that you **must** set the height of the parent element of the canvas, otherwise with maintainAspectRatio: false the height will be zero.

This is what worked for me using Bootstrap 4 cards (inline style for illustration):

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body" style="height: 400px;">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then adding these this to the options:

```
options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false
}
```

By default responsive is set to true.

This also allows the easy use of responsive breakpoints and media queries to resize the chart.

Comment: I'm having a problem with this. I set the height of the parent element, I added the **responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false**. And when I resize the window to make it bigger, it works! but when resize it to make it smaller again, the chart stays big.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to break the aspect ratio you can use the `maintainAspectRatio` option from the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-common-chart-configuration). Your height and width should be taken from the canvas set values then or use css to set styles for the canvas element.

```
options: {
    responsive: false, 
    maintainAspectRatio: false
}
```